# filter data by type and show first item of every type

Tags: angularjs

I have this array:

Controller:

```
$scope.data = [
    {id:1, name:"a", type: "letter"},
    {id:2, name:"1", type: "number"},
    {id:3, name:"b", type: "letter"},
    {id:4, name:"2", type: "number"},
    {id:5, name:"c", type: "letter"},
    {id:6, name:"3", type: "number"},
  ];
$scope.dataLimit = 1;
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in data | orderBy: 'type' | limitTo: dataLimit">
<label ng-bind="'name: ' + user.name"></label>
<label ng-bind="'type: ' + user.type"></label>
```

I tried to filter data by type and I want to show the very first data of every type, in this case would be:

- name: a type: letter
- name: 1 type: number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupBy` filter which is a part of [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

Here is your example
https://jsfiddle.net/24sk3ye5/

Answer (score 0):

You can write your labels like this:

```
 <label>name {{user.name}}</label>
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, but your answer doesn't give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom `filter` which actually returns the first object for each type.

Like this:

```
app.filter('orderByType',function(){
  return function(input) {
    var output = [];
    output.push(input[0]);
    var firstType = input[0].type;
    var i = 1;
    var len = input.length;
    for(i; i<len; i++) {
      if(input[i].type != firstType) {
        output.push(input[i]);
        return output;
      };
    };
  }
})
```

Then use the filter in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in data | orderByType | limitTo: dataLimit">
```